# How can I convert this join to LINQ syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to retrieve all tools used by products with `X = 14`, how can I convert this select to LINQ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM Product p
INNER JOIN ProductTool pt ON pt.Product_ID = p.ID
INNER JOIN Tool t ON t.ID = pt.Tools_ID
WHERE p.X = 14
```

Is `GroupJoin` what I need or what?

```
tools.GroupJoin(products, t=>, p=>, ...)
products.GroupJoin(tools, p=>, t=>, ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have foreign keys setup correctly, the entity framework should pick that relationship up and you should be able to simply do:

`var tools = from p in products where p.X == 14 select p.Tool;`

Comment: Thanks, this enlightened me a lot... Actually it is very simple `return context.Product.Where(p => p.X == id).SelectMany(t => t.Tools).Distinct().ToList();`